# Does Room and LiveData has addressing bug?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

I have some data (count) in my room. I store those from the server while authentication. Then, I display those data in my activity. I use LiveData because if something updates the count, my activity will show the updated count. I save count data as Int, My error is while I show my count data, that data is not my declared type.

This is my viewModel's code. I get data from dataManager as LiveData.

```
val dbData: LiveData<EntityCompany> = dataManager.selectCompany()
    val savedArticle: LiveData<Int> = dataManager.selectSaveArticleCompany()
    val savedBook:LiveData<Int> = dataManager.selectSaveBookCompany()
    val downloadedResume: LiveData<Int> = dataManager.selectDownloadedResumeCompany()
    val post: LiveData<Int> = dataManager.selectPostCompany()
```

This is my activity's code. I observe data from vm ( My View Model instance ) and show it in my activity's views.

```
vm.downloadedResume.observe(this, Observer {
            log("downloadedResume is $it")
            resumeCount.text = it.toString()
        })

        vm.post.observe(this, Observer {
            log("post is $it")
            jobCount.text = it.toString()
        })

        vm.savedArticle.observe(this, Observer {
            log("savedArticle is $it")
            articleCount.text = it.toString()
        })

        vm.savedBook.observe(this, Observer {
            log("savedBook is $it")
            bookCount.text = it.toString()
        })
```

This is the DataManager's code of CRUD with the database.

```
  override fun selectSaveArticleCompany(): LiveData<Int> {
        return database.getEntityCompanyDao().selectSaveArticleCompany()
    }

    override fun selectSaveBookCompany(): LiveData<Int> {
        return database.getEntityCompanyDao().selectSaveBookCompany()
    }

    override fun selectSaveResumeCompany(): LiveData<Int> {
        return database.getEntityCompanyDao().selectSaveResumeCompany()
    }

    override fun selectDownloadedResumeCompany(): LiveData<Int> {
        return database.getEntityCompanyDao().selectDowndedResumeCompany()
    }

    override fun selectPostCompany(): LiveData<Int> {
        return database.getEntityCompanyDao().selectPostCompany()
    }
```

This is the EntityDao that give me my data as LiveData.

```
@Query("SELECT savedArticles FROM COMPANY_TABLE")
    fun selectSaveArticleCompany(): LiveData<Int>

    @Query("SELECT savedBooks FROM COMPANY_TABLE")
    fun selectSaveBookCompany(): LiveData<Int>

    @Query("SELECT savedResumes FROM COMPANY_TABLE")
    fun selectSaveResumeCompany(): LiveData<Int>

    @Query("SELECT downloadedResumes FROM COMPANY_TABLE")
    fun selectDowndedResumeCompany(): LiveData<Int>
```

What I face in my activity is : androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData@2abb917 : instance of my count data.[image]

Comment: please show the code where you are setting data to the view

Comment: vm.downloadedResume.observe(this, Observer {
            log("downloadedResume is $it")
            resumeCount.text = it.toString()
        })

        vm.post.observe(this, Observer {
            log("post is $it")
            jobCount.text = it.toString()
        })

        vm.savedArticle.observe(this, Observer {
            log("savedArticle is $it")
            articleCount.text = it.toString()
        })

        vm.savedBook.observe(this, Observer {
            log("savedBook is $it")
            bookCount.text = it.toString()
        })

Comment: please post this editing the question

Comment: The DataManager is just a proxy between the ViewModel and the DAO?
You are not doing any additional work there?

Comment: @YanayHollander DataManager is singleton and there are some abstract fun of CRUD with database. I correct and fill in my question.

Comment: @KyawLinnThant when you print the log("post is $it") which type is "it"? it's an Integer? it seems that "it" is the LiveData himself and when you set the text as it.toString() it prints the object reference. try it.value. But it should not be this way, you need to observe the LiveData when you expect to receive Integer in the Observer callback